# esper A event logic and/or B event epl

Tags: logic, esper

Requirement: 
1. when A event and B event arrives in 5 sec, output C event
2. when A event or B event arrives, output C event

could I write epl like this:"insert into C select * from A.std:lastevent(), B.std:lastevent()"
but it doesn't work
how should it be? please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The A or B:

```
select * from A#lastevent as a full outer join B#lastevent as b
```

Lets do the A and B, depending on what exactly "arrives in 5 sec" really means. This here uses "#lastevent#time(5)" with an inner join to keep the last event not older than 5 seconds:

```
select * from A#lastevent#time(5) as a, B#lastevent#time(5) as b
```

Please clarify "arrives in 5 sec". Sample pattern instead:

```
select * from pattern[every a=A -> b=B where timer:within(5)]
```

The output event has two columns 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: thank you very much! "arrive in 5 sec" is not important, i want to know how to output C event. Can  "insert into C select * from A#lastevent full outer join B#lastevent
" work?

Comment: Assign a name to the joined streams using "as". I have edited the reply. i.e. "from A#lastevent as a"